# How to wait for the site to return the data using Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wrote a script using beautifulsoup4 , the script basically brings the list of ciphers from the table present on a web page.

The problem is my python script doesn't wait for the returned content of the web page and either breaks or says 'list index out of range'. The code is as follows:

```
ssl_lab_url = 'https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d='+site
req  = requests.get(ssl_lab_url)
data = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
 print CYELLOW+"Now Bringing in the LIST of cipher gathered from SSL LABS for "+str(ssl_lab_url)+CEND
        for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
           sleep(0.01)
           table = soup.find_all('table',class_='reportTable', limit=5)[-1]
           data = [ str(td.text.split()[0]) for td in table.select("td.tableLeft")]
        print CGREEN+str(data)+CEND
        time.sleep(1)
```

It sometimes return NOTHING in `data`  or says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiple_scan_es.py", line 79, in <module>
    scan_cipher_ssl(list_url )
  File "multiple_scan_es.py", line 62, in scan_cipher_ssl
    table = soup.find_all('table',class_='reportTable', limit=5)[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I need to wait here , how to do so ?

Comment: this page user JavaScript to get data from server and display it. `requests` and `BS` doesn't execute JavaScript so you can't get this data this way. You need Selenium to control browser which can execute JavaScript or use other tool which execute JavaScript. Or you have to get urls which use JavaScript and use it with `requests`

Comment: How much effort will it require me to change the script? because of this issue @furas i wanna know the areas to tweak if i use those

Comment: Selenium uses your browser Chrome/Firefox to render page (and run JavaScript) and gives you function like `wait(time)` to wait before you get HTML with all modifications made by JavaScript.

Comment: other method: first use `Developer Tools` in Chrome or `Firebug` in Firefox to "spy" communication between browser and server to get urls used by JavaScript and later you can use this urls in your script with `requests` - it needs more manual work with `Developer Tools` but later you have script which doesn't have to wait for data as Selenium does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking that this page use JavaScript to get data but it use old HTML method to refresh page.

It adds HTML tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content='**time**; url>` and browser will reload page after **time** seconds.

You have to check this tag - if you find it then you can wait and you have to load page again. Mostly you can reload page without waiting and you get data or you find this tag again.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

site = 'some_site_name.com'
url = 'https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d='+site

# --- 

while True:
    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

    refresh = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'http-equiv': 'refresh'})
    #print 'refresh:', refresh 

    if not refresh:
        break

    #wait = int(refresh[0].get('content','0').split(';')[0])
    #print 'wait:', wait
    #time.sleep(wait)

# ---

table = soup.find_all('table', class_='reportTable', limit=5)

if table:
    table = table[-1]
    data = [str(td.text.split()[0]) for td in table.select("td.tableLeft")]
    print str(data)
else:
    print "[!] no data"
```

Comment: ahh , so this refresh is what i need

Answer (score 1):

If the data isn't present in the original HTML page but is returned from JS code in the background, consider using a headless browser, such as PhantomJS, with Selenium. [Here's an example](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/).

Comment: How much effort will it require me to change the script? because of this issue

Comment: It shouldn't take more than a few lines, but you need a bit of work on your code to begin with. Looking at the output of SSL Labs, you're not taking into consideration when a site has multiple servers (eg. google.com). You don't get a report initially, but a list of servers. Check it out.

Comment: Also, why the weird indentation?

Comment: because i have only 2 servers at backend